# Batch file Start program

Tags: batch-file, call, autoit

M'kay, so I've written a few batch files before, so I'm not completely new to them, but this is stumping me. What I'm trying to do is run a .exe file from a batch file. Here's the Batch script:

```
@echo off
:start
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd "C:\Users\Zac\Dropbox\SoundCloud"
set n=0
for %%f in (*.html*) do (
set /A n+=1
set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
move "!file[%rand%]!" C:\Users\Zac\Temp
start "~dp0Link_Open.exe"
echo %time%
timeout 70 > NUL
echo %time%
goto start
```

So from my understand, this moves a random .html file from one directory to another, this works, I've used it a lot, the only issue is the "Start" command, I don't use this very often. the "Link_Open.exe" is in the same folder as my .bat, but I've tried running it with the full directory written in, I've tried quotations, no quotations, brackets, no brackets, START, start, Start, Call, CALL, call, and none of them work, I'm always getting the same error "Link_Open.exe cannot be found, have you written it correctly"

The only reason I can possibly think of that would be why it wouldn't work, is that the .exe was written in AutoIT and then compiled...but that shouldn't effect it should it?

Running the batch file will result in a random file being moved, and then an error coming up, and then repeating.

What am I doing wrong?

Ps: Running the Link_Open.exe does what it's supposed to do, so there's no errors there, the only issue I'm having is opening it with .bat.

I'm still very new to Autoit, but if someone could show me a script to move a random .html file with Autoit, I could just combine the two scripts together couldn't I?

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to `link_open.exe` ? If the application is located in any directory on the `path`, then it *should* be executed. I believe that there are some overgrown anti-virus systems that prevent execution of applications until they are specifically authorised. It's best to include a dummy pair of rabbits' ears (`""`) after a batch `start` because the first quoted argument may be consumed as a windows title - but this is probably not the case here. Need to know precisely where the executable is and where `%~dp0` is (display it in the batch - `echo %~dp0` )

Comment: @Zachary Wight Your "start "~dp0Link_Open.exe"" is missing the % before the ~

Answer (score 1):

Provided that your bat file and exe file are in the same directory as you said, try changing:

```
START Link_Open.exe
```

to:

```
start "%~dp0Link_Open.exe"
```

- `%~dp0` expands to the current batch script's path
- `start` equivalent to `START`, it doesn't matter
- enclosed in quotes in case your path has spaces like `C:\My Documents`, thus keeps the whole path as one argument, instead of being misinterpreted as being multiple arguments separated by space

### Error Explanation

Your error: `Link_Open.exe cannot be found...` is precisely that, batch can't find `Link_Open.exe`. Normally it would, because when you just give a program without full absolute path, it checks the current working directory. This defaults to where the batch script is. But notice you actually changed the current working directory with this line:

```
cd "C:\Users\Zac\Dropbox\SoundCloud"
```

Thus, unless you happen to have `Link_Open.exe` in that SoundCloud directory, or unless you had any code to `cd` back to the batch script's directory containing the exe, or unless you happen to have `Link_Open.exe` in `%PATH%`, then there is no reason batch would automatically know to check the original directory that the script was run from.

Thus we try to refer to `Link_Open.exe` in a way that batch will know how to find it. One way is if we did absolute path `C:\path\to\Link_Open.exe` however to keep things portable, I recommend `%~dp0` which expands to `whatever path of the current batch script`, and thus batch is able to find `Link_open.exe` again.

Comment: `start` takes the first parameter in quotes as a windows title. Therefore it should read: `start "" "%~dp0Link_Open.exe"` (empty dummy title)

Comment: @user454038 So I tried the "%~dp0Link_Open.exe", and it opens a second command prompt window from my SoundCloud directory, this extra window does nothing, I can enter commands manually, but that's it. I tried putting Link_Open.exe into the SoundCloud directory, same thing happens. Moving both .bat and .exe results in the same thing again. Have I typed something wrong? (I've edited my original post with the updated script.)

Comment: some programs work with just `start programname.exe` but I'm not sure what Link_Open.exe normally does. What happens when you make a simple batch file `test.bat` in the same folder as Link_Open.exe, and `test.bat` : `start "%~dp0Link_Open.exe"`? Does this alone work?  Now per @Stephan said, if that doesn't work if create and edit`test2.bat`: `start "" "%~dp0Link_Open.exe"` does that work instead?

Answer (score 0):

1. You change directory to C:\Users\Zac\Dropbox\SoundCloud and then try to start Link_Open.exe which is left in script directory.
2. So next step you use ~dp0 variable to get folder from script executed, but there is missed leading %: you must write %~dp0
3. Even though you'll fix it, maybe Link_Open.exe also depend on current working directory? *start* allows to set up CWD: `start "window header" /D "%~dp0" "%~dp0Link_Open.exe"`

To debug: add `echo` before `start` and add `pause` next line. `start` command will be printed with all variables expanded. You'll see if the something is wrong - e. g. you may copy and test via Start -> Run.

Comment: @user454038 using the line start "" "%~dp0Link_Open.exe" works, this is exactly what I was looking for. Just a quick question though, why do I need the empty "", does this just point to the directory the files in? If so, why doesn't manually pointing it there work?

Comment: @ZacharyWight this is optional title of new window. Sometimes `start` works without this option, but sometimes, as you can see, not.